# python plotting with twiny() doesn't position ticks and destroys aspect-ratio

Tags: python, matplotlib, aspect-ratio

I have created a function to plot many similar plots of contours. I am showing the minimal form of what I am doing. In this minimal example I would like to put only ticks at (0,0) A, (3,0) B, (3,3) C, (0,3) D, where A,B,C,D the labels of the ticks. I can get it to work up to putting A and B. When I introduce `twiny()` to create C and D ticks nothings seams to work any-more. Ticks are not placed where expected, and aspect ration is destroyed. I tried using `host_subplot` from `mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1`, but it didn't fix this.

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot2DFS(fign,x,y,z):

    fig = plt.figure(fign)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, adjustable='box-forced', aspect='equal')
    ax.set_title('Iso-surf contour')
    ax.contour(x, y, z)

    ax.spines['left'].set_position('center')
    ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')
    ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')

    ax.tick_params(axis='y',which='both', right='off', left='off', labelleft='off')
    ax.tick_params(axis='x',which='both', bottom='off', top='off')

    ax.xaxis.set_ticks([0.0,3.0])
    ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(['A','B'])

    bx = ax.twiny()
    bx.tick_params(axis='x',which='both', bottom='off', top='off')
    bx.xaxis.set_ticks([0.0,3.0])
    bx.xaxis.set_ticklabels(['D','C'])

    return

delta = 0.025
x = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, delta)
y = np.arange(-2.0, 2.0, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
plot2DFS(1,X,Y,Z)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The aspect ratio is just fine, you see a perfect circle, don't you?

Concerning the labels and their position you need to tell matplotlib that you want equal x limits. Put `bx.set_xlim(ax.get_xlim())` at the end of your function.

Comment: The aspect ratio is correct but look what happens to the image. The axes are not at the border, or where they would automatically be. Also if you don't save and simply tell python to show() the plot the axis move with the border independently of the image scaling.

Comment: It's not clear to me what exactly the problem is. To me the plot looks fine, but I don't know what you are trying to achieve.